# How to replicate the "Script Table As... Drop And Create..." SQL Server Management Studio action in SMO?

Tags: c#, sql-server, automation, scripting, smo

I am looking to automate script generation for versioning purposes for our SQL Server Database by using the C# Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo package. I am fiddling with the ScriptingOptions class to try to get tables scripting exactly how you would right-click, script table as, drop and create. I do not seem to be able to get the settings to match quite how SSMS does it (which is how we have been manually doing it so far). I am struggling to find posts online or documentation on what the ScriptingOptions class properties do.

I think the key parts are the USE database, full schema names, Drop Constraints, drop table if exists, create table with primary key, and adding the defaults. I know it will generate pieces of this that may need to be combined via string concatenation, but some I haven't gotten at all.

An abridged example from SSMS:

`USE <databasename>`

`ATLER TABLE <table> DROP CONSTRAINT <constraint1>`

`ATLER TABLE <table> DROP CONSTRAINT <constraint2>`

`...`

`IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].<table>') AND type in (N'U'))`

`DROP TABLE [dbo].[<table>]`

`GO`

`/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[ACCOUNT]    Script Date: 2/26/2024 12:50:43 PM ******/`

`SET ANSI_NULLS ON`

`GO`

`SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON`

`GO`

`CREATE TABLE [dbo].[<table>](`

`...`

`PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED...`

`ALTER TABLE <table> ADD DEFAULT...`

etc.

The ScriptingOptions class properties I am working with so far are the following:

```
{
    EnforceScriptingOptions = true,
    IncludeDatabaseContext = true,
    AllowSystemObjects = false,
    SchemaQualify = true,
    DriAllConstraints = true,
    Indexes = true,
    DriDefaults = true,
    NoCollation = true
}
```

Edit:
Here is my output as is:

```
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[<table>](
    <columns>...
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
        [<column1>] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_ACCOUNT_CLOSEDATE] ON [dbo].[<table>]
(
        [<column1>] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[<table>] ADD  DEFAULT (' ') FOR [<column1>]
GO
...
<more ADD DEFAULTS>
```

OR is there a better way to automate this? Looking to script tables, views, functions, and stored procedures.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you should add what you actually missing from the SMO output. Your question is way too vague as it is in my opinion

Comment: Fair enough. Added. @siggemannen

Comment: Why do you actually need it the same? Surely what it captures is enough for change tracking?

Comment: I want to be able to execute the scripts in an automated fashion as well. I admit I don't know much about the script generation, but if SSMS automatically includes dropping constraints, I imagine that we want them included in our new scripts as well. Also it would minimize changes on the first newly-scripted check-in.

Comment: `ScriptDrops = true` is perhaps what you're looking for besides what you have? The docs are available here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.scriptingoptions?view=sql-smo-160

Comment: I will give the ScriptDrops another try. I have already been to the docs page and I don't think they are particularly useful (not to mention have typos). I'm not sure how I am supposed to figure this out aside from trial and error when a property like DriIndexes has no definition at all...  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.scriptingoptions.driindexes?view=sql-smo-160#microsoft-sqlserver-management-smo-scriptingoptions-driindexes